# How to retrieve and analyse data from a MS SQL Server using Hadoop, Hive and Sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I want to do analysis on data which is in database(MS SQL Server). So how can I Bring that data on HDFS with the help of Sqoop/Hive? Is it possible with Hive/Sqoop?
Please suggest me how can we do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft recently released a [SQL connector for sqoop](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27584). There are few ETL tools (open source and not) that also connect from SQL to Hadoop (like Talend etc.)